# Как удалить из строки все символы после (

Tags: php

Есть строка, например "AK-47 | Красная линия (Factory New)"

Мне нужно сначала в зависимости от того, что в скобках, задать нужное значение в переменную(ну это я и сам смогу, только нужно записать все что в скобках в переменную), потом убрать " (Factory New)".

То есть была строка "AK-47 | Красная линия (Factory New)", а теперь "AK-47 | Красная линия" и в другой переменной значение "Factory New".

как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть разные способы, но исходить нужно из того, насколько могут быть различны вариации входных данных. Первое, что напрашивается, это регулярные выражения, при том, что я далеко не большой их поклонник:

```
preg_match('/(.*)\s\(([^()]+)\)$/', 'AK-47 | Красная линия (Factory New)', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Или таким образом:

```
$result = preg_split('/[()]/', 'AK-47 | Красная линия (Factory New)', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($result);
```

Можно обойтись без них, при условии, что формат строк будет именно таким, как вы показали в примере. Т.е. разбить строку по открывающей скобке, если вы уверены, что такая всегда будет в единственном числе:

```
$result = array_map(function($a){
    return trim($a, ' ()');
}, explode('(', 'AK-47 | Красная линия (Factory New)'));
print_r($result);
```

Вот еще один вариант:

```
$str = 'AK-47 | Красная линия (Factory New)';
$bracket_pos = strpos($str, '(');
echo substr($str, 0, $bracket_pos);
echo trim(substr($str, $bracket_pos+1), ')');
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать с помощью регулярных выражений выделить значение в скобках.

```
preg_match("(.*?)\((.*?)\)", $string, $new_value);
```

Он разложит ваше выражение на группы. В группе один будет надпись до скобок, в группе два надпись в скобках.
Доступ к ним можно получить следующим образом:

- `$new_value[1]` - 1 группа
- `$new_value[2]` - 2 группа

Для более гибкой настройки советую почитать о регулярных выражениях и для теста этот ресурс: https://regex101.com/

Comment: for($i=0;$i<count($lfdata);$i++)
 {
 preg_match("(.?)((.?))", $lfdata[$i]->name, $flt);
 
 $lfdata[$i]->name = $flt[1];
 
 echo $lfdata[$i]->name; 
 }

Comment: И выводит ошибку Unknown Modifier '('

Comment: Экранизация съелась) добавьте символ \ перед 5 и 10 символом

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'AK-47 | Красная линия (Factory New)';
$first_str = trim(strtok($str, '('));
$second_str = trim(strtok(')'));
echo "First: $first_str\n";
echo "Second: $second_str\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант в коллекцию ответов:

```
$string = "AK-47 | Красная линия (Factory New)";

echo preg_replace('~\s?\([^)]+\)~', '', $string);// AK-47 | Красная линия
echo preg_replace('~[\s\S]+[(]|[)]*~', '', $string);// Factory New
```